# Error Falta la siguiente plantilla de correo electronico started PRESTASHOP

Tags: php, email, mercadopago, prestashop, mercadolibre

Prestashop: 1.7.2.4

Mercadopago: v1.0.8 - de Mercado Pago <<< VERSIÓN MODULO

Versión PHP: 5.6.31

Versión de MySQL: 5.6.36-cll-lve

Método de correo electrónico: Estás utilizando la función PHP mail().

Hola a todos, tengo el siguiente error cuando completo un formulario de compra, le doy pasar a a comprar me figura esto. Aclaro puedo detallar envió, domicilio medio de pago, pero cuando estoy en el ultimo paso me da ese error.
*

> Error - Falta la siguiente plantilla de correo electrónico: started

*

Me orientan como solucionarlo o donde puedo mirar?

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que te falte la traducción de ese email. Si tienes acceso a los archivos, ve a themes/tuTienda/mails y asegúrate de que en todas esas subcarpetas (como mínimo debe estar una llamada 'en') existen los mismos archivos traducidos al idioma que corresponda la carpeta.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Me he descargado el módulo y tras analizarlo he localizado el problema. Durante la instalación del módulo se han creado los estados necesarios automáticamente y a todos se les ha indicado que deben enviar emails por defecto.

Sin embargo solo cuatro de ellos tienen plantillas, que son (en ingles, no se si los tendras traducidos) Transaction in Process, Transaction Pending, Transaction Chargedback y Transaction Pending.

El resto de estados no poseen plantillas en el módulo y aún así se les ha indicado que deben enviar un email cuando un pedido cambia a ese estado.

La solución sería revisar los estados y desmarcar la opción de enviar email en la configuración de prestashop. En prestashop 1.7 si no me equivoco se encuentra en Configuración > Parametros de tienda > Configuracion de pedidos y ahí se encuentra la pestaña "Estados". Busca el estado de inicio de transaccion (si no esta traducido sería "Transaction started") y desmarca la opción "Enviar un correo electrónico al cliente cuando su pedido cambie de estado."

Comment: Gracias por responder dentro de mi theme no dispongo de una carpeta de /emails pero en /modules/mercadopago/mails si encontre varios archivos. Y no encontre "started" que es el que no lo encuentra.
El problema es el siguiente, cree los dos archivos con el nombre "started" html y txt.
Como se si es esa la verdera carpeta o existe otra? dentro de esa carpeta /modules/mercadopago/mails hay otros archivos como los siguientes:
charged_back.html
charged_back.txt
in_mediation.html
in_mediation.txt
in_process.html
in_process.txt
pending.html y txt. etc.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta con mis investigaciones, espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente lo solucioné desde parametros de la tienda => Configuración de Pedidos => Estados y deshabilite el envío de mails para in_process

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]